# How do you calculate combinations with fractions (eg, "$\frac13$ choose $2$")?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinations, binomial-coefficients

I was given "$\frac13$ choose $2$" and asked to compute. I checked the answer and it's $-\frac19$, but I have no clue how to arrive at this answer.

How do you deal with fractions in the combination formula?

Answer (score 4):

The number of combinations is usually found using the factorial function $n!$ There is a standard mathematical function, called the Gamma function, which generalizes the factorial function to all real numbers (in fact all complex numbers) except for negative integers. For positive integers, $\Gamma(n)=(n-1)!$. Note $\Gamma(1)=0!=1$.

The gamma function has the properties that $\Gamma(1)=1$ and that $\Gamma(x+1)=x\Gamma(x)$.

With the usual definition of $~\displaystyle \binom{n}{r}$ as $~\displaystyle  \frac{n!}{(n-r)!\space r!}$ , two of the factorials will involve the gamma function because $n$ and $n-r$ are fractions, while the third won't need to because $r$ is an integer.

Now we will use $\Gamma(1\frac{1}{3})$ instead of $(\frac{1}{3})!$ and we will use $\Gamma(-\frac{2}{3})$ instead of $(-1\frac{2}{3})!$ .

Because of the second property of the Gamma function, $$\Gamma(1\frac{1}{3})=\frac{1}{3}\times\Gamma(\frac{1}{3})=\frac{1}{3}\times-\frac{2}{3}\times\Gamma(-\frac{2}{3})$$ and so $~\displaystyle \binom{n}{r}=\frac{n!}{(n-r)!\space r!}=\frac{\Gamma(1\frac{1}{3})}{\Gamma(-\frac{2}{3})\space 2!}=\frac{\frac{1}{3}\times-\frac{2}{3}\times\Gamma(-\frac{2}{3})}{\Gamma(-\frac{2}{3})\space 2!}=\frac{\frac{1}{3}\times-\frac{2}{3}}{1\times2}=-\frac{1}{9}$

which is the given answer.

Answer (score 4):

A generalisation of the binomial coefficient is given for real (or even complex) values $\alpha$ by
\begin{align*}
\binom{\alpha}{n}:=
\begin{cases}
\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)\cdots(\alpha-n+1)}{n!}&n\geq 0\tag{1}\\
0&n<0
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Using (1) we can write
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\binom{\frac{1}{3}}{2}}
=\frac{\frac{1}{3}\cdot\left(-\frac{2}{3}\right)}{2\cdot 1}
&\color{blue}{=-\frac{1}{9}}
\end{align*}

The formula (1) can be found for instance as formula (5.1) in *[Concrete Mathematics](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/%7Er97002/temp/Concrete%20Mathematics%202e.pdf)* by R. L. Graham, D. Knuth and O. Patashnik.

Answer (score 2):

> How do you calculate combinations with fractions?

By generalizing the normal definition of $~\displaystyle \binom{n}{k}$.

When $n \in \Bbb{Z^+}$ and $k \in \{0,1,2,\cdots, n\}$,

then you have that

$$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k![(n-k)!]}. \tag1 $$

Re-express (1) above as

$$\frac{n!}{(n-k)!} \times \frac{1}{k!}. \tag2 $$

Then, for $k > 0$, re-express (2) above as

$$n \times (n-1) \times (n-2) \times \cdots \times (n+1-k) \times \frac{1}{k!}. \tag3 $$

The re-expression in (3) above provides the necessary definition of $~\displaystyle \binom{1/3}{2}$.  Note also, that when $n$ is a positive integer, that the definition in (3) remains consistent with the standard definition of $~\displaystyle \binom{n}{k}.$

Comment: So for fractions, because they're less than one, there would only be the n term multiplying the (n + 1 - k) term over k factorial and not any of the (n-1)(n-2)... terms?

Comment: @W.Han No, that is wrong.  Assuming that $k \in \Bbb{Z^+}$, the number of factors in the numerator will be $k$.  This is expressed by the product $$n \times (n-1) \times \cdots \times (n+1-k).$$